# Mavericks - strange behavior creating simlink in root directory

Tags: terminal, macos, bash

I want to create a simlink called `/home`, that points to `/Users`.  The command `sudo ln -s Users home` (executed in /) should work; at least, I've demonstrated that the syntax is correct by creating a similar simlink in my home directory) but it's not working well in root.  I somehow managed to create an actual directory, that now can't be removed ("resource is busy").  Then I cd'ed into /home and tried to run

```
/home$  sudo mkdir chap
mkdir: chap: Operation not supported
```

Anyone understand what's going on?  Or should I keep my cotton-pickin' fingers out of /?

Answer (score 3):

`/home` is already used by `automount`, see `/etc/auto_master` and the various man pages for details.